# MySQL group by issue

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having a strange problem with MySQL and would like to see if the community has any thoughts:

I have a table 'tbl' that contains

```
 ____________
| id | sdate  |
```

And I'm trying to execute this query:

```
select id, max(sdate) as sd from tbl where id in(123) group by id;
```

This returns no results.
However, this query:

```
select id, sdate from tbl where id in(123);
```

Returns many results with id's and dates.

Why would the top query fail to produce results?

Comment: Are you missing commas for your IN clause?

Comment: No. And the query above has only 1 item in the IN clause.

Comment: I can't believe it's possible

Comment: Well, whether you believe it is possible or not is rather irrelevant, since, well, it is possible, and occurring. Read into corrupt indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the index was corrupt. Running the following solved the issue:

```
REPAIR TABLE tbl;
```

Comment: Seemed like a possibility when I mentioned it -- since in the working case it could ignore the index. :)

Answer (score 1):

So IDs in this table aren't distinct, right?  For example, it could be a list of questions here on StackOverflow with a viewed date, and each question ID could appear multiple times in the results.  Otherwise, if the IDs are always unique then there's no point in doing a GROUP BY on them.  When you're restricting the results to a single ID you don't technically need the GROUP BY clause since MAX() is an aggregate function that will return a single row.

What's the datatype of sdate?  int/datetime?

It's perfectly fine to supply a single ID to an IN() clause; it just can't be blank: IN().

Is it possible to provide the output of "DESCRIBE tbl;" and a few example rows?

Comment: Correct, the ID is non-distinct. And the group by is necessary when specifying multiple items in the IN(). The data type of the columns is case_id=int and sdate=datetime.

Comment: Yeah, I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing with MySQL 5.1.37.  It might have something to do with the indexes on your table and when they're being used or ignored between those two queries.  Can you output a "SHOW INDEXES FROM tbl"?  Try "REPAIR TABLE tbl".

Comment: 'tbl', 0, 'PRIMARY', 1, 'id', 'A', 3681817, , '', '', 'BTREE', ''
    'tbl', 0, 'PRIMARY', 2, 'sdate', 'A', 3681817, , '', '', 'BTREE', ''
    'tbl', 0, 'PRIMARY', 3, 'source', 'A', 3681817, 2, '', '', 'BTREE', ''

Comment: 'id', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'PRI', '0', ''
'sdate', 'datetime', 'NO', 'PRI', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ''